# Trouble with Capybara and Admin User permissions (and Devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

Devise for User registration and login.

Admins are set using the rails console (setting the admin boolean to true).

Rspec and FactoryGirl.

Unfortunately, I wrote my app before writing tests (the best lessons are learned the hard way). I am now learning rspec and writing a test suite for the app.

I have controller permissions and view permissions set up, for admins and non-admins, which DO work in practice (I know this through thorough browser manual testing).

In this case, I have an "Admin" link in the header which is displayed when a user is logged-in and is also an admin.

My StaticPagesController also has an effective before_action setup so no-one can access the admin page unless they are logged-in and are also an admin.

I wrote some tests for this, and thought I had it sorted, until I noticed that, when making changes to the specific /features spec file which contains these tests, guard runs only those tests and passes them. However, when I run the entire test suite, those same tests fail. I totally confused by this.

I think it may have something to do with Devise, but I just don't know.

spec/features/user_and_role_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

def manually_create_user
    visit new_user_registration_path
    fill_in('user_first_name', :with => 'Test')
    fill_in('user_last_name', :with => 'User')
    fill_in('user_email', :with => 'testuser@email.com')
    fill_in('user_password', :with => 'testuser')
    click_button('Sign up')
end

def create_user_and_login_as(type)
    user = FactoryGirl.create(type)
    visit(new_user_session_path)
    fill_in('user_email', :with => user.email)
    fill_in('user_password', :with => user.password)
    click_button('Log in')
end


describe 'with users and roles' do  

    context "if user is not an admin" do

        it "does not allow any user to visit the admin page if not logged-in" do
            visit(admin_path)
            expect(current_path).to eq(root_path)
        end

        it "does not allow a new user to visit the admin page" do 
            manually_create_user
            visit(admin_path)
            expect(current_path).to eq(root_path)
        end

        it "does not allow a student to visit the admin page" do 
            create_user_and_login_as(:student)
            visit admin_path
            expect(current_path).to eq(root_path)
        end

        it "does not allow a teacher to visit the admin page" do 
            create_user_and_login_as(:teacher)
            visit admin_path
            expect(current_path).to eq(root_path)
        end

    end


    context "if user is an admin" do

        it "allows an admin user to visit the admin page" do 
            create_user_and_login_as(:admin_user)
            click_link 'Admin'
            expect(current_path).to eq(admin_path)
        end

        it "allows a teacher_admin to visit the admin page" do 
            create_user_and_login_as(:teacher_admin_user)
            click_link 'Admin'
            expect(current_path).to eq(admin_path)
        end

    end

end
```

The tests in the context "if user is not an admin" all FAIL when running the full test suite. They all fail with the same error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(current_path).to eq(root_path)

       expected: "/"
            got: "/admin"

       (compared using ==)
```

Which, to me, means the admin page was accessible, when it shouldn't have been. In my browser, the admin page link cannot be seen, neither can the page be accessed by manually typing in the url, unless the user is signed in and is an admin.

The tests in the context "if user is an admin" all PASS when running the full test suite.

spec/factories/users.rb:

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do |f|
        f.first_name    { Faker::Name.first_name }
        f.last_name     { Faker::Name.last_name }
        f.email         { Faker::Internet.email }
        f.password      { Faker::Internet.password(8) }
        f.admin         false

        trait :student do
            type "Student"
        end

        trait :teacher do 
            type "Teacher"
        end

        trait :admin do 
            admin true
        end

        factory :admin_user,            traits: [:admin]
        factory :student,               traits: [:student]
        factory :teacher,               traits: [:teacher]
        factory :teacher_admin_user,    traits: [:teacher, :admin]

    end
end
```

static_pages_controller.rb:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :admin?, only: [:admin]

  def home
    @testimonials = Testimonial.all
  end

  def admin
    @groups = Group.all

    @users = User.all

    @students = Student.all

    @teachers = Teacher.all
  end

  private

  def admin?
    unless signed_in? and current_user.admin == true
        redirect_to root_path, notice: "You must be a signed-in admin to view this page"
    end
  end

end
```

static_pages_helper.rb:

```
module StaticPagesHelper

    def allowed_to_see_admin_link?
        signed_in? && current_user.admin
    end

end
```

models/user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
  validates :admin, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }

  scope :newest_first, -> { order("created_at DESC") }
  scope :order_by_first_name, -> { order("first_name") }

  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end

  def unassigned?
    type != "Student" and type != "Teacher"
  end

  def can_view_materials?
    admin || type == "Teacher" || type == "Student" && groups.any? # So only current students can view the Materials page.
  end

  def testimonial_owner?(testimonial)
    id == testimonial.student_id
  end

end
```

Relevant part of the _header.html.erb partial:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <% if allowed_to_see_admin_link? %>
          <li><%= link_to "Admin", admin_path %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'devise'

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
    gem 'byebug'
    gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
    gem 'spring'
    gem 'better_errors'
    gem 'binding_of_caller'
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'guard-rspec', require: false
    gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

group :test do
    gem 'faker'
    gem 'capybara'
    gem 'launchy'
    gem 'database_cleaner'
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

users in the schema:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,     null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "admin",                  default: false
    t.string   "type"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
  end
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :materials

  root 'static_pages#home'

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }

  get 'admin' => 'static_pages#admin'

  resources :groups
  resources :users
  resources :students
  resources :teachers
  resources :testimonials
  post 'assign_to_group' => 'students#assign_to_group' # Could have been 'patch', but default in the controller method is 'post', so I left the method as default and changed this route to 'post'. Doesn't NEED to be patch.
  post 'remove_from_group' => 'students#remove_from_group'
  post 'unassign_teacher' => 'groups#unassign_teacher'
  post 'assign_as_student' => 'teachers#assign_as_student'
  post 'assign_as_teacher' => 'students#assign_as_teacher'
  post 'add_student' => 'groups#add_student'
  post 'remove_student_from_group' => 'groups#remove_student_from_group'
```

Comment: In your spec - try checking for something that the user actually would/not see on the admin page eg `expect(page).not_to have_content("Welcome Mr Admin")` or whatever is actually on the logged-in admin page - if you can see that then yes, you'll need to figure out why people are automatically logged into admin. Otherwise it might be that they're on the admin-login page???

Comment: Also, style points: use `&&` and `||` instead of `and` and `or` (read why here: http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/) Secondly: `current_user.admin == true` this is pretty dangerous... what if you had accidentally forgotten one of the `=` - that's a hard bug to spot and will not actually cause your code to fail... just to silently let all users see the admin page. It's a good habit to *always* do this instead: `true == current_user.admin` That will fail loudly if you accidentally use `=` instead

Answer (score 0):

The reason your tests are failing are that you are checking the current_path before the redirect has finished.  Basically you're calling visit(xxx), which sets the current_path to xxx, and then immediately reading back xxx, while the server returns a redirect back to / and then the browser changes current_path to /.  As long as you're using Capybara 2.5+ you should be using the have_current_path matcher which will retry for a bit, thereby giving the redirect time to be processed

```
expect(page).to have_current_path(root_path)
```